# How to modify the PKEY_COPYRIGHT field using IPropertyStore Interface

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, windows-shell

While trying to modify this field, the IProertyStore::SetValue() returns with an AccessDenied error code. My interface is initialized with the ReadWrite flag.

i've ALSO tried to modify this property while the file's handler remained open, but i received an HRESULT error code from the SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName() saying the file is already in use(well, this makes sense :O ?)

just to mention, updating values such as PKEY_TITLE, PKEY_Comment, and so on ended succesfully.

thanks!

Comment: Check the result of  IPropertyStoreCapabilities::IsPropertyWritable first

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take change copyright and other strings of programs , you can use Restorator 2007 or Resource Hacker